# How can I convert a PHP stdCLass object to XML?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I use this code to connect to a web service that allows me to retrieve a stock of products for e-commerce. However, the latter returns a stdClass Object (photo below).

```
$wsdl = "https://sinex-saas.com/blabla/Services/WebServiceStandard.asmx?WSDL";

$password = "????";
$username = "????";

$options = array(
    'user' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$response = $client->RecupererEtatStock($options);
$presque = $response->RecupererEtatStockResult;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($presque);
```

My goal is to convert this stdClass object to XML so that I can use it for a WordPress plugin. Do you know how to convert a stdClass to XML with PHP?

[image: stdClassObject photo]

Comment: XML is an extremely flexible (or, as its name puts it, eXtensible) language, so "converting to XML" isn't really a well-defined operation. What would you like the XML to look like? Also, none of the code you've shown here is really relevant - where the object came from doesn't make a difference to what you do with it next - unless what you're actually asking is how to get the original XML from the SOAP response, in which case the answer is [`$client->__getLastResponse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to build a generic convert. It is a lot easier just to read a specific object structure and create a DOM from it. This allows you to define the structure, validate and reformat the values, ignore unneeded values, ...

```
$data = getData();

$document = new DOMDocument();
// create and append a document element
$document->appendChild(
    $stock = $document->createElement('stock')
);

// iterate data array
foreach ($data->EtatStock as $stockData) {
    // create and append an element for each item
    $stock->appendChild(
        $item = $document->createElement('item')
    );
    // add a child element with text content
    $item
      ->appendChild($document->createElement('CodeMag'))
      ->textContent = $stockData->CodeMag;
    $item
      ->appendChild($document->createElement('LibMag'))
      ->textContent = $stockData->LibMag;
    // add value as an attribute 
    $item->setAttribute('quantity', $stockData->QteStock);
}

$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();

function getData() {
    $json = <<<'JSON'
{
    "EtatStock": [
        {
            "CodeMag": "001",
            "LibMag": "SO SHOCKING",
            "QteStock": 2000
        }
    ]
}    
JSON;
    return json_decode($json);
}
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stock>
  <item quantity="2000">
    <CodeMag>001</CodeMag>
    <LibMag>SO SHOCKING</LibMag>
  </item>
</stock>
```